# How to refresh selected tab instead all tab using Syncfusion ej2?

Tags: syncfusion

I have a few tabs opened and I would like to refresh on the tab selected tab instead refresh on every tab. Is there any way to refresh the selected tab instead of refreshing all tab using Syncfusion ej2?

```
if (args.item.text == "Refresh") {
                    //location.reload();
                    var obj = document.getElementById('appTab').ej2_instances[0];
                    console.log(obj);
                    obj.refresh(); //refresh all tabs
```

Answer (score 0):

With latest version of syncfusion package(18.3.51), you can use the public method `refreshActiveTab` to refresh the selected tab alone. Please refer the following sample.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/refresh-active-tab?file=index.ts